# No speed gains from Cython

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, cython

I am trying to define a function that contains an inner loop for simulating an integral.

The problem is speed. Evaluating the function once can take up to 30 seconds on my machine. Since my ultimate goal is to minimize this function, some extra speed would be nice.

As such, I have tried to get Cython to work, but I must be making a severe mistake (likely many of them!). Following the Cython documentation, I have tried to type my variables. After doing so, the code is just as slow as pure Python. This seems strange.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np 
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np
import minuit

data = np.genfromtxt('q6data.csv', usecols = np.arange(1, 24, 1), delimiter = ',')  

cdef int ns    = 1000                 # Number of simulation draws
cdef int K     = 5                    # Number of observed characteristics, including            constant
cdef int J     = len(data[:,1])       # Number of products, including outside
cdef double tol   = 0.0001            # Inner GMM loop tolerance
nu = np.random.normal(0, 1, (6, ns))  # ns random deviates

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)


def S(np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] delta, double s1, double s2, double s3, double s4,  double s5, double a):
    """Computes the simulated integrals, one for each good.
    Parameters: delta is an array of length J containing mean product specific utility levels
    Returns: Numpy array with length J."""
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] mu_ij = np.dot((data[:,2:7]*np.array([s1, s2, s3, s4, s5])), nu[1:K+1,:])
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] mu_y  = a * np.log(np.exp(data[:,21].reshape(J,1) +  data[:,22].reshape(J,1)*nu[0,:].reshape(1, ns)) - data[:,7].reshape(J,1))
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] V = delta.reshape(J,1) + mu_ij + mu_y
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] exp_vi = np.exp(V)
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] P_i = (1.0 / np.sum(exp_vi[np.where(data[:,1] == 71)], 0)) * exp_vi[np.where(data[:,1] == 71)] 
    cdef int yrs = 19
    cdef int yr
    for yr in xrange(yrs):
        P_yr = (1.0 / np.sum(exp_vi[np.where(data[:,1]== (yr + 72))], 0)) *   exp_vi[np.where(data[:,1] == (yr + 72))]
        P_i  = np.concatenate((P_i, P_yr)) 
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] S = np.zeros(dtype = "d", shape = J)
    cdef int j
    for j in xrange(ns):
        S += P_i[:,j]
    return (1.0 / ns) * S

def d_infty(np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] x, np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] y):
    """Sup norm."""
    return np.max(np.abs(x - y)) 

def T(np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] delta_exp, double s1, double s2, double s3, double s4,  double s5, double a):
    """The contraction operator.  This function takes the parameters and the exponential
    of the starting value of delta and returns the fixed point.""" 
    cdef int iter = 0
    cdef int maxiter = 200
    cdef int i
    for i in xrange(maxiter): 
        delta1_exp = delta_exp * (data[:, 8] / S(np.log(delta_exp), s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, a))                    
        print i
        if d_infty(delta_exp, delta1_exp) < tol:                                       
            break
        delta_exp = delta1_exp
    return np.log(delta1_exp)


def Q(double s1, double s2, double s3, double s4, double s5, double a):
    """GMM objective function."""  
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] delta0_exp = np.exp(data[:,10])                                                     
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] delta1 = T(delta0_exp, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, a)
    delta1[np.where(data[:,10]==0)] = np.zeros(len(np.where(data[:,10]==0)))            
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] xi =  delta1 - (np.dot(data[:,2:7],   np.linalg.lstsq(data[:,2:7], delta1)[0]))   
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] g_J = xi.reshape(J,1) * data[:,11:21]
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] G_J = (1.0 / J) * np.sum(g_J, 0) 
    return np.sqrt(np.dot(G_J, G_J))
```

I have profiled the code, and it seems to be the function S, the integral simulator, that is killing performance. Anyway, I would have expected at least some speed gains from typing my variables. Since it produced no gains, I am led to believe that I am making some fundamental mistakes.

Does anybody see a glaring error in the Cython code that could lead to this result?

Oh, and since I am very new to programming, there is surely a lot of bad style and things slowing the code down. If you have the time, feel free to set me straight on these points as well.

Comment: How big is `data` ? Could you split it into pieces where column 1 == { 0, 1, ... 18, 71 } once, outside the inner loop ?

Comment: So the data has 2237 rows and 21 columns.  The rows can be partitioned into subsets corresponding to years from 1971 to 1990.  The hurdle for me has been finding a quicker way to do that operation since I have to divide each entry for a given year only by the sum of entries corresponding to that year.  Surely there is a better way to accomplish this than what I have implemented, but I have failed to find it!

Answer (score 35):

Cython can produce an html file to help with this:

```
cython -a MODULE.py
```

This shows each line of source code colored white through various shades of yellow. The darker the yellow color, the more dynamic Python behaviour is still being performed on that line. For each line that contains some yellow, you need to add more static typing declarations.

When I'm doing this, I like to split parts of my source code that I'm having trouble with onto many separate lines, one for each expression or operator, to get the most granular view.

Without this, it's easy to overlook some static type declarations of variables, function calls or operators. (e.g. the indexing operator x[y] is still a fully-dynamic Python operation unless you declare otherwise)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  This looks quite useful.  I have searched around for how to add this to my setup.py without luck.  Does anybody have advice for how to accomplish this?

Comment: You don't need to add it to your setup.py; you should just run it at the command line.

Comment: I like to create a little Makefile for little random commands like this. Then 'make cython' will both perform the cythoning (using your setup.py as usual) and then run the command above. On Windows, I like to install Cygwin and put the bin directory on my Path, so I have access to 'make' and other unix-y commands, even from a DOS prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about indexing - it's a real life-saver. Relevant information regarding this can be found at http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#efficient-indexing

Answer (score 17):

Cython doesn't offer automatic performance gains, you have to know its internals and check the generated C code.

In particular if you want to improve loops performances, you have to avoid calling Python functions in them, which you happen to do a lot in this case (all the `np.` calls are Python calls, slicing, and probably other things).

See [this page](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html) for general guidelines about performance optimization with Cython (the -a switch really is handy when optimizing) and [this one](http://wiki.cython.org/tutorials/numpy) for specificities when optimizing numpy code.

Comment: I thought the 'cimport numpy' tells Cython to use C functions for numpy, instead of the Python ones. This would mean the 'np' calls are not Python calls, whereas everything else is. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes you misunderstood, the numpy declarations from the cimport are only used in cdef statements I think, and also give access to numpy's C API which is very different: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.html

Answer (score 11):

You could definitely speed up your code by using more of Numpy's capabilities.

For instance:

```
cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] S = np.zeros(dtype = "d", shape = J)
cdef int j
for j in xrange(ns):
    S += P_i[:,j]
```

would be much faster and legible as

```
S = P_i.sum(axis=1)
```

You also repeat some calculations, which thus take twice more time than necessary.  For instance

```
np.where(data[:,1]==(yr + 72))
```

could be calculated only once and stored in a variable that you could reuse.

You also perform a lot of reshaping and slicing: it could help to have your variables be in a simpler format from the beginning on.  If possible, your code would be much clearer, and optimizations could be much more obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about calculating S, that is much cleaner!  Also, defining variables for the sliced data arrays did speed things up a bit.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually I would disagree, with your opening statement. The code will become faster by using more direct processing in C, and fewer calls to numpy routines.  Also according to the cython documentation, accessing an array by slicing (P_i[:,j]) is inefficient. http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html

Comment: @DaveP: I'm not sure I follow you: my point is *exactly* that, as you say, "slicing is inefficient".  Many Numpy functions allow you to bypass any need for slicing, as in my first example.  Furthermore, since Numpy does a lot of "direct processing in C", it is hard write code that runs faster than its equivalent Numpy function.

Comment: As the link I gave explains, indexing of the type P_i[:, j] is slow (this is the slicing we wish to avoid), whereas writing explicit loops and using indexing of the type P_i[k, j] is fast.  As far as I understand the difference is due to the first case requiring a function call, but the second case can generate inline code.  When you generate inline code, the compiler can more easily optimise the whole algorithm as one, rather than having functions as bottlenecks.

Comment: @DaveP: Thank you for the explanation.  So, we both agree on the fact that a single loop on `i` that uses `P[:, i]` is to be avoided.  You suggest to use a full loop and Cython, while I suggest to use no loop at all and Numpy.  Your approach is probably the fastest, while my simpler/shorter solution is probably about as fast except for the function call (which is hopefully negligible compared to the calculation time).

Answer (score 6):

Will a profiler help you figure out which part is slow? I like to run programs using the standard library profiler:

```
python -O -m cProfile -o profile.out MYAPP.py
```

and then view the output from that in the 'RunSnakeRun' GUI:

```
runsnake profile.out
```

A RunSnakeRun can be installed from here:
http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/

[image: RunSnakeRun screenshot]

Comment: The question is about cython code, not python code, so your answer isn't directly helpful.  However the point about profiling is valid, details about profiling in cython can be found at http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/profiling_tutorial.html

Comment: +1 for the profiling: profiling is indeed the first step towards optimization.  Thank you also for mentioning runsnake: it looks very promising!

Answer (score 1):

Taking the advice given here, I have spent more time profiling the above code.  To hopefully clean things up a bit I defined

I have profiled the code a bit more and have a better idea of which pieces are the slowest.  I additionally defined

```
X = data[:, 2:7]
m_y = data[:, 21].reshape(J,1)
sigma_y = 1.0
price = data[:, 7].reshape(J, 1)
shares_data = data[:,8]
```

Then it is the following lines that are eating up most of the total time.

```
mu_ij = np.dot((X*np.array([s1, s2, s3, s4, s5])), nu[1:K+1,:])
mu_y  = a * np.log(np.exp(m_y + sigma_y*nu[0,:].reshape(1,ns)) - price)
V = delta.reshape(J,1) + mu_ij + mu_y
exp_vi = np.exp(V)
P_i = (1.0 / np.sum(exp_vi[np.where(data[:,1]==71)], 0)) *  exp_vi[np.where(data[:,1]==71)] 
for yr in xarange(19):
    P_yr = (1.0 / np.sum(exp_vi[np.where(data[:,1]==yr)], 0)) * exp_vi[np.where(data[:,1]==yr)]
P_i  = np.concatenate((P_i, P_yr))
```

I get the impression this is an overly cumbersome way to achieve my goal.  I was hoping somebody might be able to provide some advice on how to speed these lines up.  Maybe there are Numpy capabilities I am missing?  If this problem is not sufficiently well specified for you to be helpful, I would be happy to provide more details on the context of my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Please don't "answer" your own question with more questions. Instead, update your original question if relevant, otherwise ask a new question.

Comment: I apologize.  I was unclear on what the proper procedure was for updating my question.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting data *only*, after your comment on 28 Nov:

```
import sys
import time
import numpy as np

def splitdata( data, n, start=1971 ):
    """ split data into n pieces, where col 1 == start .. start + n """
        # not fancy, fast enough for small n
    split = n * [None]
    for j in range(n):
        split[j] = data[ data[:,1] == start + j ]
    return split  # [ arrays: col1 0, col1 1 ... ]

#...........................................................................
N = 2237
ncol = 21
start = 1971
n = 20
seed = 1
exec "\n".join( sys.argv[1:] )  # run this.py N= ...
np.set_printoptions( 2, threshold=100, suppress=True )  # .2f
np.random.seed(seed)

print "N=%d  ncol=%d  n=%d" % (N, ncol, n)
data = np.random.uniform( start, start + n, (N,ncol) )
data[:,1] = data[:,1].round()
t0 = time.time()

split = splitdata( data, n, start )  # n pieces

print "time: %.0f us splitdata" % ((time.time() - t0) * 1e6)
for y, yeardata in enumerate(split):
    print "%d  %d  %g" % (start + y, len(yeardata), yeardata[:,0].sum())
```

-->

```
time: 27632 us splitdata  # old mac ppc
1971  69  136638
1972  138  273292
...
```

Answer (score -7):

The "fundamental mistake" is that you expect good performance in long loops from Python. It's an interpreted language, and switching between implementations and ctyping does nothing to this. There are a few numeric Python libraries for fast computing, mosly written in C. For example, if you already use `numpy` for arrays, why not you go further and use `scipy` for your advanced math? It will increase both readability *and* speed.

Comment: Cython is not an implementation of Python, it's a Python-like language that is compiled to C. Also Python is *not* an interpreted language.

Comment: I have used Scipy a bit, but I am not sure where I could use it here for extra performance.  Do you have any specific suggestions about where I could invoke some of its capabilities here?

Comment: The whole point of Cython is that it is specifically designed to accelerate the performance of python, potentially achieving C like performance in many cases.  So there is no "fundamental mistake" in this question.

Comment: Saying Python is not interpreted, while technically correct, is misleading without giving the context. When you run a Python program, the 'interpreter' converts your source to bytecode, which it then executes. From a black-box perspective, it behaves exactly like a traditional interpreter, including the performance characteristics.

Comment: On reflection, not all of the performance characteristics - I was wrong about that. But some of them! :-)