# Why is Cython (extension module) as slow as Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, anaconda, numba

I am searching for ways to get a better python performance. For example: fib.py

```
import datetime

def fibonacci(n):
 a,b = 1,1
 for i in range(n-1):
  a,b = b,a+b
 return a

t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
fibonacci(590000)
t2 =  datetime.datetime.now()

t=(t2-t1).total_seconds()

print("Time:",t)
```

took 4.337s.
I also wrote a extension module with a setup.py file which generates a fib.pyd file which can then be included. (Compiled with distutils)

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup (ext_modules = cythonize("fib.pyx"))
```

It took 4.275s.
Am I doing it wrong, or  why is Cython not improving the runtime?
(Numba took  1.03s)
Any help/similar experience is appreciated.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264229/no-speed-gains-from-cython) give good background on what Cython actually does and what you need to do to get speed improvements. (I'm almost tempted to mark it as a duplicate, but a bit undecided)

Comment: If you're worried about performance on 2.7 use `xrange` instead of `range`.

Comment: *"I also wrote a extension module"* and without that no one can really answer your question. Edit your question and supply it.